# output an .xls error

Tags: asp.net, output

http://forums.asp.net/t/1038105.aspx/1

allows me to output an .xsl document but when I open it, instead of containing the appropriate data, it appears as if it has tried to take a screen shot of my home page and output the text through that?

any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it going in the end...was missing Response.End(); at the end of the method –